# How get total amount in MS Access SQL?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I use following query to get OrderID :

```
SELECT OrderItem.ID
     , ProductID
     , OrderID
     , Quantity
     , P.Title
     , P.CurrentPrice
     , P.ID
     , (P.CurrentPrice* OrderItem.Quantity) AS Total
FROM OrderItem
INNER JOIN Product AS P
   ON OrderItem.ProductID = P.ID
```

How can I get the total amount (Add all Total with same OrderID ) for each OrderID?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`, `SUM()`.

Comment: SELECT OrderItem.ID, ProductID, OrderID, Quantity, P.Title,P.CurrentPrice, P.ID, (P.CurrentPrice* OrderItem.Quantity) AS Total, SUM(Total)
FROM OrderItem INNER JOIN Product AS P ON OrderItem.ProductID = P.ID
GROUP BY OrderID,OrderItem.ID, ProductID, Quantity, P.Title,P.CurrentPrice, P.ID    not  work, outputs all records and SUM(Total) = Total

Comment: i try used inside MS Access query with source from other query, and it work SELECT OrderID, SUM(MainQuery.Total)
FROM MainQuery
GROUP BY OrderID
But i need use Delphi and just sql query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use  a select  form your select and group by

```
select OrderID, sum(Total) 
from (
SELECT 
    OrderItem.ID
    , ProductID
    , OrderID
    , Quantity
    , P.Title
    ,P.CurrentPrice
    , P.ID
    , (P.CurrentPrice* OrderItem.Quantity) AS Total
FROM OrderItem 
INNER JOIN Product AS P ON OrderItem.ProductID = P.ID
) t 
group by OrderId
```

Comment: Thank you so much. 
How i can join that query with 
SELECT O.ID, C.SecondName, E.SecondName, O.DateOf , O.ClientID, O.EmployeeID, O.Desc
FROM ((Client AS C INNER JOIN [ORDER] AS O ON C.ID = O.ClientID) 
    INNER JOIN Employee AS E ON E.ID = O.EmployeeID) 
        INNER JOIN Product AS P ON P.ID = O.ProductID; 
for total field in Order's table?

Comment: Your comment seems a new question  ... you should post a new well documented  question  .. is difficult understand you goal looking to the code in comment  ..  anyway if may asnwer i right please mark it as accepted  and eventually comment me the new link

Answer (score 0):

I'm only new to SQL but I think this is the solution.

```
SELECT OrderItem.ID, ProductID, OrderID, Sum(Quantity) AS Sum of Quantity, P.Title,P.CurrentPrice, P.ID, (P.CurrentPrice* OrderItem.Quantity) AS Total
FROM OrderItem INNER JOIN Product AS P ON OrderItem.ProductID = P.ID GROUP BY OrderID
```

Hope this Helps.